# was to be vs. were to be

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

The following part of text is taken from here

http://english.sakshi.com/news/2018/02/26/sridevi-death-suspected-murder-dubai-police-question-boney-hotel-staff

> Now, the body of the actress was to be flown in to India for her last rites. Members from across the film fraternity had rushed to Anil Kapoor's home where the body was to be kept for final respects
>
> **was to be** flown

Or

> **were to be** flown

I'm confused. Is ***was*** to be flown grammatically correct here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Singular: The body was to be flown.
>
> Plural: The bodies were to be flown.